# Unable to pass DateTime to class method - coercion error

Tags: powershell

I can't seem to pass a `datetime` object to any class method I write. Here is a simple version of what I'm trying and what I get:

```
class Utils {
  static [string] formatDate([datetime]$Input) {
     if($Input.Equals([datetime]::new(0))) { return "" }
     return $Input.ToString("MMddyy")
 }
 static [string] joinDates([datetime[]]$Input) {
     return ($Input | ForEach{ $_.ToString("MMddyy")}) -Join ", "
 }
}
```

And when I try this command I get an error:

```
> [Utils]::formatDate((Get-Date))
> No coercion operator is defined between types '`System.Object[]' and 'Utils'.
> At line:1 char:1
> + [Utils]::formatDate((Get-Date))
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException
```

However, the following works:

```
> [Utils]::joinDates(@((Get-Date), (Get-Date)))
> 120518, 120518
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing or don't know, but on the surface this seems simple/basic enough that it should just work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$Input` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6) in PowerShell, and your attempt to use `input` as a parameter name in `Utils.formatDate()` is what causes this odd behavior. Change the parameter name and the method will behave as expected:

```
class Utils {
  static [string] FormatDate([datetime]$datetime){
    if($datetime -eq [datetime]::new(0)){ return "" }
    return $datetime.ToString("MMddyy")
  }
  static [string] JoinDates([datetime[]]$datetimes){
    return ($datetimes | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString("MMddyy") }) -join ", "
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense, thankyou! I had that passing thought but since it worked for `joinDates` I dismissed it as a possibility. I guess the `[datetime[]]` type could be "coerced" to the automatic variable type? Thanks again!

Comment: @someone1 exactly right! `$Input` is always an `ArrayList` enumerator, so when you pass and array, powershell figures that it can convert that to an `ArrayList` from which the enumerator can be produced :)